# How to create a BCD to binary encoder that supports multi digit numbers using only logic gates

Tags: converter, adder, binary

I've been thinking so long about how can I make a BCD to binary encoder that can encode BCD numbers like for example 11 or even 32767 into binary form (11 ---> 1011) but using only logic gates.
I tried experimenting with expanding the circuit from third image but it does not work.
I need this for my binary adder.
Any ideas?
The second image is exact 1bit adder im using inside of my 16 bit adder

[image: This is the binary addition circuit i use, its just double the size going up to A15, B15 etc.].

[image: Full bit adder im using]

[image: BCD to binary encoder i tried using]

Comment: The Fig 4.45 is a "one-hot to BCD" encoder, which hasn't much of anything to do with your task

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I make an a decimal to binary encoder using logic gates (16-bit, tolerates numbers up to 32767)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688706/how-can-i-make-an-a-decimal-to-binary-encoder-using-logic-gates-16-bit-tolerat) If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: If both operands as well as the required result are multi-digit BCD, creating BCD adders may be way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some multiplying, but luckily one multiplicand will be fixed.

If your input BCD digits are ijk, you can push k straight into your final adder.  The digit j has to be multiplied by 10, or 0xA, or 0b1010.  That means the term is represented in binary by j<<1 + j<<3.  Then add k in binary to the running total.

Your term i needs to be multiplied by 100, or 0x64, or 0b01100100.  So, add together j<<2 + j<<5 + j<<6, and add the result to the running total for a binary representation.

Of course, you can rearrange all the adders to minimize propagation delays etc., but the multiplication by shift-and-add is just a matter of hooking the inputs up correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying you have to encode the 10^n value for each BCD digit and multiply that digit by that number.  I don't know of a way to limit the operations to 2^n values, as powers of 10 are never powers of 2 (except for 1).  To decode binary->BCD, you just  pass each half-byte (nybble) through if it's <=9, or if >9 subtract 0xA and pass a carry to the next stage.  On the second nybble, the carry has to have 2 carry bits so it can carry up to 2, the third nybble has to pass carry values up to 4, and so on.  The 8th nybble will need to carry up to 42.